# attr value sowing undefined in console

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am trying to get the data-icons value but it shows undefined in console.

### My codes are

```
<ul class="list-icons" data-icons="star">
```

Js files

```
var icon = $('ul.list-icons li').attr('data-icons');
console.log(icon);
```

It shows undefined

Comment: `var icon = $('ul.list-icons').attr('data-icons');`

Comment: "My code is", not "my codes are." "Code" is a mass noun, like "water" or "air".

Answer (score 2):

You're selecting an `li`, but your attribute is on a `ul`. Remove the `li`.

```
var icon = $('ul.list-icons').attr('data-icons');
// No li here -------------^
console.log(icon);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<ul class="list-icons" data-icons="star">csdc
</ul>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {

        var icon = $('ul.list-icons').attr('data-icons');
        alert(icon);
    });
</script>
```

no need to write "li"